# VBA Excel formula with dynamic table name

Tags: excel-formula

I have an issue for writing a formula in VBA

the formula in Excel is very simple, if the word Test appears in a row of one of my 4 tables, then give me the sum of the column4 :

```
=SUMIF(Table1[Column1]:Table4[Column1],"Test",Table1[Column4]:Table4[Column4])
```

In VBA, it would be (and it works) :

```
ws.Range("B1").Formula ="=SUMIF(Table1[Column1]:Table4[Column1],""Test"",Table1[Column4]:Table4[Column4])"
```

My issue is that I have a dynamic number of tables, so my biggest table is "Table" & i

I really don't know how to write in VBA the formula, I always have an error:

```
ws.Range("B1").Formula ="=SUMIF(Table1[Column1]:""Table"" & i &""[Column1]"",""Test"",Table1[Column4]:""Table"" & i &""[Column4]"")"
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

```
Sub Formula()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = Worksheets(1)

i = ws.Range("A1")

If i = 1 Then

ws.Range("B1").Formula = "=SUMIF(Table1[Column1]:Table1[Column1],""Test"",Table1[Column3]:Table1[Column3])"

End If

If i = 2 Then

ws.Range("B1").Formula = "=SUMIF(Table1[Column1]:Table2[Column1],""Test"",Table1[Column3]:Table[Column3])"

End If

If i = 3 Then

ws.Range("B1").Formula = "=SUMIF(Table1[Column1]:Table3[Column1],""Test"",Table1[Column3]:Table3[Column3])"

End If

If i = 4 Then

ws.Range("B1").Formula = "=SUMIF(Table1[Column1]:Table4[Column1],""Test"",Table1[Column3]:Table4[Column3])"

'What I would like :

'ws.Range("B1").Formula = "=SUMIF(Table1[Column1]:Table" & i & "[Column1],""Test"",Table1[Column4]:Table" & i & "[Column4])"

End If

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `ws.Range("A1").Formula ="=SUMIF(Table1[Column1]:Table" & i & "[Column1],""Test"",Table1[Column4]:Table" & i & "[Column4])"`

Comment: It's not working as well, I forgot to say that my table name is more like :
Table" & i & "_client

Comment: Why don't you show us the exact Excel formula and tell us what exactly needs to be changed? If this going to be used in a loop, then at least show us the complete 'loop' code.

Comment: No, this is not in a loop, my tables are under each other. The amount of the table varies.
Under the last tables, I have formulas to calculate the sums, and if there is not the right amount of table I have #REF! error. So the formula must be written using VBA just after the creation of the table. In my very simple example, the formula doesn't work.
It could be this formula as well : 
=SUM(Table1[[#Totals],[Amount]],Table2[[#Totals],[Amount]])
Just instead of Table 2 it would need Table i where i is located in A1